# Selecting data to be loaded into table view Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a table view controller and above the cell is a segmented control. The segmented control has 3 options. Past Posts, Current Posts, and Future Posts. I am trying to figure out how to load the specific data into the table view depending on what index is selected on the segmented control.

For example if Past Posts is selected I want to load the Past Post data from Parse Server into the table view. Or of Future Posts is selected load the Future Posts date from Parse Server into the table view.

I am not at all sure how to load the "selected" data, then remove and load different data if the index changes. Any help is much appreciated!

Also, I know how to fetch data from Parse Server. I only mention that to explain where my data is coming from.

Comment: If past post selected then, load the past post for entire tableView or just selected cell??

Comment: Say there are 5 "Past Posts" saved to Parse Server. If "Past Posts" is selected then it will load 5 cells with the Past Post data. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something creating a controller that performs the fetch, the parsing, and returns a closure with the associated identifier if it ever changes, you can still use this approach. Something along these lines.

**UPDATE**

With help from [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37495836/1027812) I wanted to put a little  context into my answer for completeness.

```
typealias PostsCompletionClosure = (requestIdentifier : String, posts : [Post])->Void

class PostController {

    func fetchPastPosts(requestIdentifier : String,
                        completion : PostsCompletionClosure,
                        queue : dispatch_queue_t?) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

            let queryParams = ["status" : "past"]

            self.performQuery(queryParams, completion: { (requestID, posts) in
                dispatch_async(queue != nil ? queue : dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   completion(requestIdentifier : requestIdentifier, posts : posts)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func fetchCurrentPosts(requestIdentifier : String, 
                           completion : PostsCompletionClosure, 
                           queue : dispatch_queue_t?) {
        // Same as Above
    }

    func fetchFuturePosts(requestIdentifier : String, 
                          completion : PostsCompletionClosure, 
                          queue : dispatch_queue_t?) { {
        // Same as Above
    }

    private func performQuery(queryParams: [String : String], 
                              completion : PostsCompletionClosure) {

         let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")

         for {key, value) in queryParams {
             query.whereKey(key, equalTo: value)
         }

         query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
            guard let error == nil else {
                // Handle Error
                return
            }

             if let results = objects as? [Post] {
                dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   completion(requestIdentifier : requestIdentifier, posts : posts)
             }
          })
    }
}
```

You can even create a post request queue for the segment requests, and cancel all prior operations if you are about to start a new one, thus never even giving it an opportunity to reload your data in the first place.

Here is a possible approach on how to implement the viewController :)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var segnmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

    var posts: [Post]?
    var activeRequestId: String = ""

    // This should prolly be injected or a singleton
    let postsController = PostController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        didSelectSelegment(segnmentControl)
    }

    @IBAction func didSelectSelegment(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        posts = nil
        tableView.reloadData()

        activeRequestId = "\(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)"

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            self.postsController.fetchPastPosts(activeRequestId, completion: { (requestIdentifier, posts) in
                 self.reloadDataWith(requestIdentifier, posts : [Post])
            })
        case 1:
            self.postsController.fetchCurrentPosts(activeRequestId, completion: { (requestIdentifier, posts) in
                 self.reloadDataWith(requestIdentifier, posts : [Post])
            })
        case 2:
            self.postsController.fetchFuturePosts(activeRequestId, completion: { (requestIdentifier, posts) in
                 self.reloadDataWith(requestIdentifier, posts : [Post])
            })
        default:
            fatalError("unexpected segment index")
        }
    }

    func reloadDataWith(requestIdentifier : String,
                        posts : [Post]) {

        if self.requestIdentifier == requestIdentifier {
            self.posts = posts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
     }                         
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of isolating the view controller from complicated query logic. You might want to make the `posts` parameter optional, though (and pass an `NSError?`, too) so that parse failures can be successfully be identified by the view controller.

Comment: @Rob merged your content, and setup a good template to get started for almost anyone :)

Comment: @Anton I really like what you have come up with. I'm working on implementing this and will get back to you with any questions I might have.

Comment: @m1234 I'm glad to hear, I'm a huge proponent of breaking things up into their respective pieces. You could even go a step further by adding a queue, and cancelling prior operations. And even a step further by abstracting the methods defined in the controller to a protocol. You can then use something like Swinject to switch up the controllers without ever effecting the UI code

Comment: @Anton Adding a queue is definitely something I will work on as well. Right now my only issue is that I get the error `Use of unresolved type 'Post'` on the line `typealias PostsCompletionClosure = (requestIdentifier : String, posts : [Post])->Void`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be that as the segmented control changes, you would initiate a `PFQuery` that would populate your model, and then trigger the reloading of the table. For example, something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var posts: [Post]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didChangeValueForSegmentedControl(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        // first empty the table

        posts = nil
        tableView.reloadData()

        // prepare new query

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            query.whereKey("status", equalTo: "past")
        case 1:
            query.whereKey("status", equalTo: "current")
        case 2:
            query.whereKey("status", equalTo: "future")
        default:
            fatalError("unexpected segment index")
        }

        // now perform query

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                // report error
                return
            }

            guard let searchResults = objects as? [Post] else {
                // handle situation where results were not an array of `Post` objects
                return
            }

            self.posts = searchResults
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostCell

        let post = posts![indexPath.row]

        // configure `cell` using `post`

        return cell
    }
}
```

Now, those `whereKey` clauses are certainly not right, and that would change depending how your object model was set up, but this illustrates the basic idea. Initiate `PFQuery` on the basis of which segmented control was selected and then update the results accordingly.

Now, this all makes a lot of assumptions (that you've defined your table view and specified the view controller as its data source; that you've hooked up the outlet for the table view; that you've hooked up the `IBAction` for `valueChanged` on the segmented control; that you've defined a cell prototype with a custom cell type; etc.), but it illustrates the key parts of the solution.

Comment: I'd love to merge the example code into my solution, and credit you on it, one top of adding the threading piece to my solution

Comment: @AntonDoudarev - I certainly don't mind as long as it's properly attributed. Or, perhaps simpler, you can just say something like "depending upon the complexity of the queries, I might keep the query logic in a separate controller like below, but refresh the table view like Rob did in his answer." Whatever works for you. Thanks for asking, tho.

Comment: Of course :) I really appreciate that! I haven't used Parse enough to have a sample ready to go